# Isometries and open maps

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, continuity, isometry

I've been trying to think of an example of an isometry between metric spaces that doesn't map open sets to open sets but have been having trouble coming up with an example. Open balls are mapped to open balls, but I am not entirely sure about open sets. If anyone could provide an example, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think mapping open balls to open balls would imply it maps open sets to open sets

Comment: @mathworker21 It certainly would, since every open set is a union of open balls. However, as shown in my answer, the image of a ball under an isometry is not necessarily an open ball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open balls are (in general) not mapped to open balls. Take the map $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ given by $x \mapsto (x,0)$. Clearly, $f$ is an isometry when $\Bbb R^n$, $n \in \{1,2\}$, is equipped with the Euclidean norm (or any $p$-norm). Then, $f((0,1)) = \{(x,0) : x \in (0,1)\}$ which is not an open ball in $\Bbb R^2$, not even open in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Could you clear up what I am thinking wrong here?. $f:\left(X,d\right)\rightarrow\left(Y,e\right)$ is an isometry if $d\left(x,y\right)=e\left(f\left(x\right),f\left(y\right)\right)$. If $y\in B\left(x,\epsilon\right)$, then $d\left(x,y\right)=e\left(f\left(x\right),f\left(y\right)\right)<\epsilon$, so $f\left(y\right)\in B\left(f\left(x\right),\epsilon\right)$. I thought this meant that open balls were mapped to open balls, but obviously this is not true by your example.

Comment: @Jake You have shown $f(B_d(x,\epsilon)) \subseteq B_e(f(x),\epsilon)$. You have not shown the other inclusion. Indeed, the other inclusion is false, as shown above.

Comment: @eeperly16, ah right! :) thanks!